# R Output from bugs command

Tags: r, output

I am running winbugs from R and I need to use some variables in R output. When I type `schools.sim$mean$theta[1]` in R, I get 10.2. However, when I type `schools.sim$2.5%$theta[1]` an error message come up. Any one what I am doing wrong or any other way to get the bayesian intervals?

here is an example

```
Here is the R code
library(R2WinBUGS)
data(schools)
J <- nrow(schools)
y <- schools$estimate
sigma.y <- schools$sd
data <- list ("J", "y", "sigma.y")


inits <- function(){
list(theta = rnorm(J, 0, 100), mu.theta = rnorm(1, 0, 100),
sigma.theta = runif(1, 0, 100))
}

schools.sim <- bugs(data, inits, model.file = "D:/model.txt",
parameters = c("theta", "mu.theta", "sigma.theta"),
n.chains = 3, n.iter = 1000,
bugs.directory = "D:/PROGRAMLAR/WinBUGS14/")

schools.sim
```

and this is the winbugs code which must be stored as `model.txt` in `D`.

```
model {
for (j in 1:J)
{
 y[j] ~ dnorm (theta[j], tau.y[j])
 theta[j] ~ dnorm (mu.theta, tau.theta)
 tau.y[j] <- pow(sigma.y[j], -2)
 }
mu.theta ~ dnorm (0.0, 1.0E-6)
tau.theta <- pow(sigma.theta, -2)
sigma.theta ~ dunif (0, 1000)
}
```

Dont forget to change the bugs directory where the winbugs folder is stored.

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example?

Comment: `data(schools)` fails for me, the `schools` dataset is not standardly available in R.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you must use library(R2WinBUGS). I have edited the code above. Copy and paste it please

Comment: @Paul, is it working now?

Comment: Not for me, I do not have WinBUGS, not windows. Your question is already answered by my answer. This has little to do with anything BUGS specific.

Comment: I am afraid your answer is not right in this case as schools.sim$['2.5%']%$theta[1] does not work, but thanks for your time anyway

Comment: It should be `schools.sim$['2.5%']$theta[1]`, you did not delete the %. Please read carefully.

Comment: Sorry fro that, but that one does not work either

Comment: Please define `does not work either`, what is the error.

Comment: what you is get `NULL` if you type 

    `schools.sim$"2.5%"$theta[1]`

Comment: You should type `schools.sim['2.5%']$theta[1]`, please read up on subsetting in R using `$` vs `[` or `[[`.

Comment: This time R says

    `unexpected '[' in"schools.sim$["`

Comment: Notice the `$` which is not present in my answer, but is in yours...

Comment: I am having a terrible a day. When I type yours, the output is `NULL`.

Comment: I found a way of extracting the Bayesian intervals from the output and wish to share it. `schools.sim$summary[,3]` and `schools.sim$summary[,7]` give the lower and upper limits of the bayesian intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The same behavior can be observed using `quantile`:

```
> quantile(runif(100))$0%
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "quantile(runif(100))$0"
```

Just use:

```
> quantile(runif(100))['0%']
        0% 
0.03293488
```

The issue is that `%` is a reserved character in R.